# How can I set up overflow /tmp partition?

Tags: partition, tmpfs

I run Antergos as my OS. I have several drives in my computer: a 240gb SSD, a 320gb SATA hard drive, and a 120gb IDE drive. I store most everything on the SSD because I don't generally need more room than that, and I have the IDE drive set up as a network available drive to share with my laptop. My question is, is there any way that I can set it up so that if the /tmp partition on the SSD fills up (just happened while building catalyst-total) it can start to overflow seamlessly into the SATA drive on a pre-determined partition?

Comment: Yes, tmpfs will use swap space if sufficient RAM is not available. That means you can create and activate a swap partition on the SATA drive and it will be used as well for `/tmp` provided it's a tempfs.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe I didn't realize that sooner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tmpfs` uses swap if sufficient RAM is not available. That means you can create and activate a swap partition on the SATA drive and it will be used for `/tmp`, provided it's a `tmpfs`.

In order to to that, create a swap partition and mount the swap space in your `/etc/fstab`. Furthermore, you have to ensure that the mounted `tmpfs` is of sufficient size. Use the `size` option. E.g.

```
# entries from /etc/fstab
UUID=d59ccb12-0b8e-42e4-b1e5-62e62b5b4c14 none  swap   sw        0   0
tmpfs                                     /tmp  tmpfs  size=20G  0   0
```