# linux + increase temporary the /tmp partition for installation

Tags: linux, partition

I have linux VM machines with version red-hat 4

I have the following file system

```
df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             950M  163M  739M  19% /
/dev/sda1             130M   13M  118M  10% /boot
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda6              96M   18M  899M   2% /tmp
/dev/sda3             2.8G  1.2G  1.5G  44% /usr
/dev/sda5               5G  152M  765M  17% /var
```

I need to install some oracle KIT that need **/tmp** at least **2G** , while my free **/tmp** is **96M**

Can someone advice what my alternative?  In order to install my oracle KIT

Not sure but I was thinking about to create link from /tmp to /usr but I guess I will stay with the same problem , or maybe some other creative solution ?

Please advice

Comment: Mount `/tmp` as tmpfs. Or maybe you can utilise the (existing) `/dev/shm` using symlinks.

Comment: can you give me more details about the two options , thank you ,

Comment: See [How can I set up overflow /tmp partition?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247900/12779) and [man 5 tmpfs](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmpfs&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en)

Comment: in the solution I see the UUID , can I take this UUID as is , or I need to find the UUID number ?

Comment: The UUID is only required for swap, not for the tmpfs. If you already have swap set up you can ignore that line. Tmpfs doesn't require a UUID because it's not a disk partition. And you can't use *that* UUID. Find out your UUIDs with `lsblk -f`.

Comment: so only I need to do is to add the line"tmpfs                                     /tmp  tmpfs  size=2G  0   0" in the /etc/fstab and perform mount -o remount /tmp

Comment: Yes. If you don't want it permanently no need to mess with fstab in the first place. Just do the mount on the command line: `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp -o size=2G`. Adjust the `2G` to your needs.

Comment: ok , I will do that , and if I want to umount the syntax is - uount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp ?

Comment: Almost, it's: `umount /tmp`

Comment: last question , how do I know what is the max for /tmp upgrade , for example if I want to update the /tmp to 3G with tmpfs filesys